# How to integrate the value of a variable in the body of a post request in gatling with scala

Tags: scala, post, request, gatling

I want to use the value of a variable in the body of my post request, but I don’t know how can I do because I already use a csv file as feeder to get all the other values for my query’s parameter, expect one parameter that should have as value currentTime:

So I set this variable as:

```scala
var currentTime = ZonedDateTime.now()
```

and then in body of post request I have

```scala
.body(StringBody(“”"{keys: value gotten from csv file timeNow: ( here I want to put the value of my variable currentTime)}“”")
```

How can I integrate the value of my variable `currentTime` as a value of the body query’s parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way: use one of the [built-in Gatling Expression Language functions](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/el/#built-in-functions), such as `currentTimeMillis()` or `currentDate(<pattern>)`.